# What kinds of technology would we be limited to if magic causes EMPs?

Tags: magic, technology

In an attempt to explain why things aren't as advanced as things could be with the help of both technology and magic I've made it so that each spell that is cast emits an EMP that is extremely powerful at the spell's origin(depending on the magnitudes of energies involved in the spell of course, start a fire vs explode a house) but wanes in intensity as it travels across the world like an expanding sphere. Enchanted objects emit EMPs as well, though with a shorter range and only when their conditions for performing their magic is fulfilled and they cast their own spells(like a sword enchanted to produce a wave of fire when slashed for instance).

The people aren't aware of these pulses much like how people in real life weren't exactly aware of EMPs until the 1950s when they noticed electronic equipment failed because of induced currents and voltages during some nuclear tests, but they do unknowingly make use of them to detect enchanted items or spells cast by magic users through divination spells. The use of magic is fairly universal, with even a country bumpkin knowing how to produce a tiny light at the tip of his finger or a savage knowing how to produce small sparks for the starting of a fire, so it's safe to say that the world is nearly always experiencing some sort of pulse that would make it a really bad place for electronics to be.

**What kinds of purely physics-based technology(that which doesn't involve magic) would we be limited to if magic made the world such a hostile place for electronics?**

Comment: When scientists are aware of the EMP's occurring.. and understand their workings and effect, they may simply decide not to allow this EMP phenomenon to limit development. Preventive measures like shielding off the EMP before it occurs, or in your world magic boundary spells may be composed, for that purpose.. in general: why would anything predictable, with a known and preventable effect, cause a setback  in technological  development ? https://www.euro-emc.co.uk/product/emp-shielding

Comment: this depends entirely on the intensity of frequency of the EMP's many things already emit EMP's. You emit EMP's with every muscle contraction.

Comment: EMPs can be shielded against, and it's possible to do so accidentally. All it would take was one scientist doing tests involving a metal box, and the concept of the Faraday cage could easily be born. Electronics would probably be more expensive, but if magic lacks the scaling computational capabilities that make our world run today, I'd expect a rather similar tech level--maybe even a more advanced one as researchers figure out how to use magical techniques to produce technological components.

Comment: @Goodies My thought process was that since there'd be near constant damaging effects to electronics that they may give up on developing them since they just don't seem to work or always break so it'd be seen as not worth it to try. Though now that I've thought about the ability to shield against EMPs I'm wondering if I should rather give magic some other tech-limiting property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sorts of technology can be discovered, up to the point of internal combustion engines.

The first thing is that if you want electronic technology, you probably need some circumstance where these EMPs would interfere with *magic*.

This is so they can discover that if you work magic in a room shielded by metal, you can limit it, up to preventing it entirely.  (Try putting a cell phone in a microwave and then calling it.  Faraday cages do not have to be cumbersome.)

Once these cages are in place, they can use them to experiment in magic, and as a sideline discover natural properties such as electricity.

There will be two limits on electronics:

1. What is feasible to protect with a Faraday cage
2. What is of interest to people who can do things by magic.  For instance, since you describe light spells as the simplest, electric lights will be curiosities unless someone, experimenting for fun or pure research, discovers a way to make them cheaper and/or easier than light spells.

Answer (score 2):

Anything with out an electric curent.  Guns, steam engines, hot air balloons etc. It would probably look a little like steam punk just more advanced.

The question you should be asking is what effect  Constant EMP's would have On the neurons in the brain, Or  on the nervous system.  Not a doctor so I can't tell you.  however  If I were you I would think about what kind of health problems my wizards have.